# Maven : excluding the main artifact itself from a dependency

Tags: maven, pom.xml

When adding a dependency to a POM.xml, Is it possible to exclude the main artifact itself. 
In other words I want to add a dependency to my pom and I want to download only its dependencies, not the main jar.

Here's what I want to do :

```xml
 <dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
    <artifactId>htmlunit</artifactId>
    <version>2.12</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>htmlunit</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
     </exclusions> 
</dependency>
```

I know this might seem strange but I actually have a modified version of the htmlunit project in my source folder and what I actually want is only the libraries it depends on without having to add them all to my pom.

I tried the above and it seems the htmlunit-2.12.jar is added to my project, which is exactly what I want to avoid.

Anything I could do to work around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply define a dependency to `htmlunit`'s pom instead of the jar. So you would define the dependency as follows:

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>htmlunit</artifactId>
        <version>2.12</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <!-- other project dependencies go here -->
</dependencies>
```

You will then get all dependencies defined in the pom included in your project transitively, but the htmlunit jar would not be included.

Answer (score 0):

By reading your question I can say that you wants to add dependencies mentioned in pom file of the other project jar excluding that jar.

You can achieve this by this way ,Here i show code in general Change respective attribute value as per your requirement

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>other.pom.group.id</groupId>
            <artifactId>other-pom-artifact-id</artifactId>
            <version>SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>   
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

On maven website there is a far better description on this dependency management see this [Importing dependency](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Importing_Dependencies) and [Dependency Management](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management)

Comment: This only adds the dependencies to the `dependencyManagement` section. They are not explicitly a dependency of the project - i.e. wont be included in the classpath of the project when built. You would still then need to list all the required dependencies in the `<dependencies>` section of the pom as well.